# Sir Rod Stewart's and Celine Dion's voice after 15 years i.e. Year 2035

Tags: predictive-modeling, prediction

https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk03hQn_rH1aaf7yO0q7CgN7CxPw2vw%3A1601345036018&ei=DJZyX9BW_o_j4Q-Fn77QCg&q=rod+stewart+age&oq=Rod&gs_lcp=ChNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwEAEYADIJCCMQJxBGEPsBMggIABCxAxCRAjIKCC4QsQMQFBCHAjIFCC4QsQMyBQguELEDMgUIABCxAzIFCAAQsQMyBQgAELEDOgQIABBHOgcIIxDqAhAnOgcILhDqAhAnOgQIIxAnOgUIABCRAjoICAAQsQMQgwE6AgguOgQILhAnOgQIABBDOgQILhBDUITwA1j4hwRglZIEaAFwAXgBgAHqAogB6AySAQcwLjIuNC4xmAEAoAEBsAEPyAEIwAEB&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp

https://www.google.com/search?client=ms-android-lava&sxsrf=ALeKk02wz-Vxsa8IAbrEMJeSfJ05is0jxg%3A1601489970504&ei=Msx0X7q2Ht7Dz7sPv7OQqA0&q=celine+dion%27s+age&oq=Celine+di&gs_lcp=ChNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwEAEYADIJCCMQJxBGEPsBMgUILhCxAzIFCAAQsQMyBQgAELEDMgoIABCxAxAUEIcCMgIIADICCAAyAgguOgQIABAKOgQILhAKOgoILhCxAxAUEIcCUKEbWLaSAWCBnAFoAnAAeACAAdcFiAGEF5IBDTAuOC4wLjEuMC4xLjGYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp

https://youtu.be/YlP1v8s688Q
https://youtu.be/SCDcnOWftx0

Taking example of Sir Rod Stewart with current age as 75 years, i see the same melody,sweetness in his voice.

Input dataset : Inputting all songs i.e. .wav, .mpg files sound formats sung by Sir Rod Stewart till date.

Inputting all songs i.e. .wav,.mpg files sound formats sung by Celine Dion till date.

Output : Can Machine learning prediction algorithms predict in Year 2035 when Sir Rod Stewart will be 90 years whether his voice will be as melodious and sweet which is also at the current age?

Output : Can Machine learning prediction algorithms predict in Year 2035 When Celine Dion will be 67 years whether her voice will be as melodious and sweet which is also at the current age?

Output will be sound (.wav,.mpg) files.

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-prediction-algorithm-for-machine-learning

https://www.google.com/search?q=random+forest+vs+decision+tree&oq=random+forests+v%2Fs&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l4.10570j0j7&client=ms-android-lava&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base of any experiment or model for a machine learning problem is data. While not similar there are many models which channel faces into aging them and lowering them.

This problem statement is quite similar where in one wants to know the effect a voice would have (or no effect) with the aging of a person.

If you could collect audio files of peoples voices from now and before I guess you can reach a certain level of accuracy. You could start by collecting voices of singers who have been singing for a long time. While no one sings at 90 years of age professionally you can surely work from 18 - 60 years.

You should also look up on GAN's as this will be the base of your model. You could also try to hard code a few aspects by studying the statistical variations of voices in terms of pitch, modulation etc.